# Convert CHAR to ASCII in LISP

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp

I want to write a program in LISP to get a string from the user and return the string formed by adding 1 to each char-code of the string. For example:

input: "hello123"
output: "ifmmp234"

I thought maybe I should convert the characters one by one to ASCII and then do what I want to do.

Any help with this will be so much appreciated..

Thanks

This is the code I developed. It gives me NIL in the output however. Can you help me with this:

```
(defun esi (n)
  (setf m 0)
  (loop (when (< m (length n))
          (return))
        (code-char (+ 1 (char-code (char n m))))
        (+ 1 m)))
```

Comment: This book is a gentle introduction into Lisp: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/  - free for download.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the functions [`char-code`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_char_c.htm) and [`code-char`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_code_c.htm).

*EDIT:* Regarding your code sample:

- It seems that the input to your function should be a string.  Name it such, e.g. `string`.
- That `(setf m 0)` is setting a free variable.  In this context, I must assume that `m` is never defined anywhere, so the behaviour is undefined.  You should use, for example, `let` instead to establish a local binding.  Hint: most looping constructs also give ways to establish local bindings.
- The only exit out of your loop is that `(return)`.  Since it does not get any parameters, it will always return `nil`.  You need to accumulate the new string somewhere and finally return it.
- Functions in Lisp mostly do not modify their arguments.  `(+ 1 m)` does not modify `m`.  It just returns a value that is one greater than `m`.  Likewise, `code-char` does not modify its argument, but returns a new value that is the character corresponding to the argument.  You need to bind or assign these values.
- That finishing condition is wrong.  It will either terminate directly or, if the input string is empty, never terminate.

Comment: Thanks Svante... Really useful... do you have any idea on how to write the code I am looking for?

Comment: This is the code I developed. It gives me NIL in the output however. Can you help me with this:

(defun esi (n)
  (setf m 0)
  (loop 
    (when (< m (length n)) (return))
    (code-char (+ 1 (char-code (char n m))))
    (+ 1 m)))

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few ways of doing what you want. Let's start with a function that returns a character one code-point later (there are some boundary issues here, let's ignore that for now).

```
(defun next-codepoint (char) (code-char (1+ (char-code char))))
```

Now, this operates on characters. Happily, a string is, essentially, a sequence of characters. Sequence operations should, in general, send you in the direction of the MAP family.

So, we have:

```
(defun nextify-string (string) (map 'string #'next-codepoint string))
```

Taking what's happening step by step:

- For each character in an input stringm we do:

  - We convert a character to a code attribute.
  - We increment this
  - We convert it back for a character
- Then we assemble all of these into a return value.